# JDBC driver installed but exception

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2005, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

I am using a software that requires jbdc driver (for sql server 2005), 
my java version is 1.5.0_16.

When I want to start the application, it throws me this exception :

```
java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
```

Comment: did you added jdbc driver to `classpath`?

Comment: Did you import the jar file of the jdbc?

Comment: Yes I added the jar file

Comment: I think i had similar problem with sql-server-2000 and i solve it with older jdbc jar. I used the sqljdbc_3.0.

Comment: the new exception is java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection

Comment: If u were using sql server 200 first read this thread. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2007/06/15/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-microsoft-jdbc-sqlserver-sqlserverdriver.aspx

Comment: Your URL should be jdbc:sqlserver://server:port;DatabaseName=dbname 
and Class name should be like com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver 
Use MicrosoftSQL Server JDBC Driver 2.0 http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=99b21b65-e98f-4a61-b811-19912601fdc9&displaylang=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CLASSPATH variable is the search string that Java Virtual Machine (JVM) uses to locate the JDBC drivers on your computer. If the drivers are not listed in your CLASSPATH variable, you receive the following error message when you try to load the driver:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/microsoft/jdbc/sqlserver/SQLServerDriver
```

The JDBC driver is not part of the Java SDK. If you want to use it, you must set the classpath to include the sqljdbc.jar file or the sqljdbc4.jar file. If the classpath is missing an entry for sqljdbc.jar or sqljdbc4.jar, your application will throw the common "Class not found" exception.

The sqljdbc.jar file and sqljdbc4.jar file are installed in the following location:

```
<installation directory>\sqljdbc_<version>\<language>\sqljdbc.jar
<installation directory>\sqljdbc_<version>\<language>\sqljdbc4.jar
```

The following is an example of the CLASSPATH statement that is used for a Windows application:

```
CLASSPATH =.;C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\sqljdbc.jar
```

The following is an example of the CLASSPATH statement that is used for a Unix/Linux application:

```
CLASSPATH =.:/home/usr1/mssqlserverjdbc/Driver/sqljdbc_4.0/enu/sqljdbc.jar
```

You must make sure that the CLASSPATH statement contains only one Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server, such as either sqljdbc.jar or sqljdbc4.jar.

For more information, please see:

[support ms](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313100)

[msdn ms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378526.aspx)

Comment: Note that `CLASSPATH` is not used by most methods of executing Java applications.

Answer (score -2):

Is the driver class name correct?

Shouldn't it be

```
"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
```